# Cambiar estilos haciendo scroll usando outerHeight, junto con div fixed y otro div sticky

Tags: javascript, css3, scroll

Estoy creando un efecto visible y oculto de un div `fixed` al hacer `scroll`. En conjunto con el `header` y otro div `sticky`.

El div fijo se oculta al hacer scroll pero al terminar de visualizar el header: usando `outerHeight`.

Lo que no logro es cambiar el color de fondo del div fijo mientras que sea visible (`top: 0`) pero después de pasar el header. Estando sobre el header este debe ser de fondo transparente (o poder agregar otros estilos).

Mi problema no es aplicar el estilo con `classList.add` o `style.background = ""` sino, como capturar el momento cuando esté  visible pero fuera del header.

Por ejemplo quiero esto: si el scroll es mayor al header, entonces aplicar color de fondo al divo fijo (que es visible)

```
if ( scroll > header ) headland.style.background = "red"
```

**ACTUALIZADO**

A parte de que se cambie el color de fondo (lo cual puedo lograr), necesito que `headland` sea visible junto con la navegación (`sticky`) al hacer scroll `top` (hacia arriba), pero no durante que el `header` sea visible

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => { 

let scroll = window.pageYOffset,
    headland = document.querySelector(".headland"),
    navegacion = document.querySelector(".navegacion"); 

window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
    
    let s = window.pageYOffset,
        w = window.outerHeight - 70;
    
    if(scroll < s && s > w) {
        
        headland.classList.add("top");
        //headland.classList.add("fondo");
        navegacion.classList.remove("top"); 
        
    } 
    
    /* else if(scroll > w) {
        headland.classList.add("fondo");
    } */
    
    else {
        
        headland.classList.remove("top");
        headland.classList.remove("fondo");
        navegacion.classList.add("top"); 
        
        
    }
    
    scroll = s;

});

});
```

```css
* {
box-sizing: border-box
}

:root {
--height: 50px;
--transicion: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
--color: lightblue;
--fondoVerde: rgb(47, 79, 79);
--fondoNegro: rgb(0, 0, 0);
--fondoVerdeTransparente: rgba(47, 79, 79, 0.5);  
}

html {
scroll-behavior: smooth
}

body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
font-size: 16px;
background-color: whitesmoke
}

.headland, header, .navegacion {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
width: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 1rem 1rem;
}

.headland {
position: fixed;
z-index: 1000;
top: 0;
left: 0;
height: var(--height);
transition: var(--transicion);
color: var(--color);
box-shadow: 0 0 7px #ccc;
background-color: transparent;
backdrop-filter: blur(3px)
} .headland.top {
top: -50px;
} .headland.fondo {
background-color: var(--fondoVerde)
}

header {
position: relative;
height: 100vh;
color: var(--color);
background-color: var(--fondoNegro)
}

.navegacion {
position: sticky;
top: 0;
z-index: 1001;
transition: var(--transicion);
background-color: var(--fondoVerdeTransparente); 
backdrop-filter: blur(3px)
} .navegacion.top {
top: var(--height)
}

.navegacion button {
margin: auto
}

main {
min-height: 1000px
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="CONTENT-TYPE" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Scroll</title>  
</head>
<body>
    
    <div class="headland" id="headland">
        <h1>Página de prueba</h1>
    </div>
    
    <header>
        <h1>Header</h1> 
    </header>
    
    <div class="navegacion" id="navegacion">
        <button>Botón</button>
        <button>Botón</button>
        <button>Botón</button>
    </div>
    
    <main></main>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: En tu actualización pones: "... pero no durante que el header sea visible" Esto no se entiende

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El asunto tiene las siguientes partes

- Cuando headland está en el header
- Cuando headland está fuera del header

  - Con scroll hacia arriba
  - Con scroll hacia abajo

[IntersectionObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) Es capaz de determinar cuándo un elemento sale o entra en pantalla. Entonces la lógica es: si header está fuera de pantalla, es que headland está fuera del header. Lo ocupo de esta manera porque funciona sin importar el tamaño de header, es decir, no es necesario calcular la altura. Esto se guarda en la variable "activar"

activar = true => Headland fuera del header
activar = false => Headland dentro del header

Luego con el evento scroll, toca determinar cuando sube o baja y que hacer en cada caso.

```js
const header = document.querySelector("header");
const headland = document.querySelector("#headland");
const navegacion = document.querySelector("#navegacion");
let activar = false; // false: si headland está en el header, true si ha salido
const observer = new IntersectionObserver(
    ([e]) => {
        if (e.intersectionRatio < 0.1) {
            activar = true;
        }
        else {
            activar = false;
        }
    }
    ,{ threshold: 0.1 }
);

observer.observe(header);

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    let oldScroll = 0; //para daterminar la direccion
    let altura = headland.getClientRects()[0].height;//altura de headland

    window.addEventListener("scroll", (e) => {
        if(activar)
        {
           if (oldScroll > this.scrollY) { //scroll hacia arriba
               headland.style.top = "0px";
               navegacion.style.top = altura + "px"
           }
           else{ //scroll hacia abajo
                headland.style.top = -altura + "px";
                navegacion.style.top =  "0px"
           }
        }
        else{ //restaurar posiciones cuando vuelve a pantalla el header
            headland.style.top = "0px";
            navegacion.style.top = "0px";
        }
        oldScroll = this.scrollY;
    });
});
```

```css
        * {
            box-sizing: border-box
        }

        :root {
            --height: 50px;
            --transicion: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
            --color: lightblue;
            --fondoVerde: rgb(47, 79, 79);
            --fondoNegro: rgb(0, 0, 0);
            --fondoVerdeTransparente: rgba(47, 79, 79, 0.5);
        }

        html {
            scroll-behavior: smooth
        }

        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            font-size: 16px;
            background-color: whitesmoke
        }

        .headland, header, .navegacion {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 1rem 1rem;
        }

        .headland {
            position: sticky;
            z-index: 1000;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            height: var(--height);
            transition: var(--transicion);
            color: var(--color);
            box-shadow: 0 0 7px #ccc;
            background-color: red;
            backdrop-filter: blur(3px)
        }

            .headland.top {
                top: -50px;
            }

            .headland.fondo {
                background-color: var(--fondoVerde)
            }

        header {
            position: relative;
            height: 50vh;
            color: var(--color);
            background-color: var(--fondoNegro);
        }

        div {
            height: 50px !;
        }

        .navegacion {
            position: sticky;
            top: 0;
            z-index: 1001;
            transition: var(--transicion);
            background-color: var(--fondoVerdeTransparente);
            backdrop-filter: blur(3px)
        }

            .navegacion.top {
                top: var(--height)
            }

            .navegacion button {
                margin: auto
            }

        main {
            min-height: 10000px
        }

        .no-sticky {
            background-color: forestgreen;
        }

        .headertop {
            background-color: var(--fondoNegro)
        }
```

```html
<div class="headland" id="headland">
        <h1>Página de prueba</h1>
    </div>
    <header>
        <h1>Header</h1> 
    </header>



<div class="navegacion" id="navegacion">
    <button>Botón</button>
    <button>Botón</button>
    <button>Botón</button>
</div>
<main>

</main>
```

Comment: No aparece el `headland` al hacer scroll hacia arriba. Eso es lo queisiera

Comment: @NarcisoAifuz Para confirmar: Al hacer scroll hacia abajo no mostrar headland, y con scroll hacia arriba si debe mostrar headland ???? es así?

Comment: así es. Solo quiero que esté fijo sobre el header. Pero luego, que se mueva con la navegación "sricky" ...

Comment: @NarcisoAifuz Favor valida esta nueva demo

Comment: Yo creo que esta respuesta va a ser la buena, solo faltaría explicar cómo funciona.

Comment: @Triby Lo que pasa es que ya publiqué otra respuesta, pero no había entendido bien el problema, por eso le pido a Narciso que me indique si esto es lo que busca y si es así vuelvo a editar, ya explicando bien el asunto

Comment: Creo que lo que hiciste es justo lo que quiere... aunque, como dices, es difícil de entender.

Comment: Ok @Yussef ésta si que funciona como quiero. Es que me fue díficil explicar. Como podría explicar este efecto o como se le llama?

Comment: Pero, ¿No es mucho código para algo simple? Si, pero funciona. Ahora tengo que estudiar este código porque no entiendo la estructura. Agregaste `IntersectionObserver` y `DOMContentLoaded` (que tal vez no sea necesario) pero tengo que saber bien como funcionan

Comment: @NarcisoAifuz Actualicé la respuesta, y cambié algo de código creo que ahora está más ordenado

Comment: @Yussef  excelente

Comment: Mucho mejor con la explicación. +1

Answer (score 3):

Con esta función yo resolví una situación algo parecida.

```
$(function () {
  var navigation = $("#navbar"); 

  $(window).scroll(function () {    
        var navheight = $("#navbar").height();
        var headheight = document.getElementById('header');  
        if (headheight) {  
            headheight = headheight[0].clientHeight;
            var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
            if (scroll >= headheight - navheight) {
                navigation.addClass("bg-blue");
                navigation.removeClass("bg-blue-05");
            } else {
                navigation.removeClass("bg-blue");
                navigation.addClass("bg-blue-05");
            }  
        }
  });
});
```

Esto lo que hace es cuando el scroll pasa el header la barra de navegación cambie de color. Pero puede agregarles muchas mas cosas.

Answer (score 1):

A ver si entendí: Quieres es que `headland` se mantenga visible después de que el desplazamiento oculta el encabezado, pero con otro color de fondo, y que se oculte al llegar al final de la página.

Si ese es el caso, solo necesitas tomar la altura del encabezado para agregar otro condicional; revisa los comentarios en el código para ver los cambios.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => { 

  // ¿Realmente necesitas la variable scroll? en la función basta con usar s
  let scroll = window.pageYOffset,
    headland = document.querySelector(".headland"),
    header = document.querySelector('header');
    navegacion = document.querySelector(".navegacion"); 

  window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
    let s = window.pageYOffset,
        w = window.outerHeight - 70;
        // Tomar altura de encabezado, menos altura de headland para aplicar el cambio
        h = header.offsetHeight - headland.offsetHeight;
    if(s > h && s < w) {
        // Cambiar fondo cuando el scroll sobrepase el encabezado, sin llegar hasta abajo
        headland.classList.add('fondo');
    } else if(s > w) {
        // Ocultar cuando el scroll llegue hasta abajo
        headland.classList.add("top");
        navegacion.classList.remove("top"); 
    } else {
        // Mantener formato original
        headland.classList.remove("top");
        headland.classList.remove("fondo");
        navegacion.classList.add("top"); 
    }
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

:root {
  --height: 50px;
  --transicion: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  --color: lightblue;
  --fondoVerde: rgb(47, 79, 79);
  --fondoNegro: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  --fondoVerdeTransparente: rgba(47, 79, 79, 0.5);  
}

html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}

.headland, header, .navegacion {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1rem 1rem;
}

.headland {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1000;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: var(--height);
  transition: var(--transicion);
  color: var(--color);
  box-shadow: 0 0 7px #ccc;
  background-color: transparent;
  backdrop-filter: blur(3px);
}
.headland.top {
  top: -50px;
}
.headland.fondo {
  background-color: var(--fondoVerde);
}

header {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  color: var(--color);
  background-color: var(--fondoNegro);
}

.navegacion {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1001;
  transition: var(--transicion);
  background-color: var(--fondoVerdeTransparente); 
  backdrop-filter: blur(3px);
}
.navegacion.top {
  top: var(--height);
}

.navegacion button {
  margin: auto;
}

main {
  min-height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="CONTENT-TYPE" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Scroll</title>  
</head>
<body>
    
    <div class="headland" id="headland">
        <h1>Página de prueba</h1>
    </div>
    
    <header>
        <h1>Header</h1> 
    </header>
    
    <div class="navegacion" id="navegacion">
        <button>Botón</button>
        <button>Botón</button>
        <button>Botón</button>
    </div>
    
    <main></main>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Esto funciona igual como tengo. Lo que quiero es que sea  visible al hacer scroll `top` tal como es el nav `sticky`